# How to convert csv date format to into mysql db

Tags: mysql, date, csv

At csv file, the date field is in such format:

```
2/9/2010 7:32
3/31/2011 21:20
```

I am using php + mysql for development.

I need to read it and store into mysql db.

final value to store in mysql should be format as below:

```
2010-02-09 07:32:00
```

What's the correct way of it?

Is mysql syntax alone can handle the conversion easily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

#### Example

```
STR_TO_DATE('3/31/2011 21:20', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i');
```

Comment: How about [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90498/import-csv-file-into-mysql-with-custom-data-change?noredirect=1#comment162435_90498)? Any help please? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I face the same issue and after little research this is how i resolved it-

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/dataupload.csv' INTO TABLE table1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (@d1,col2,col3,col4) 
SET col1 = date_format(str_to_date(@d1, **'%m/%d/%Y'**), **'%Y-%m-%d'**)`

Details:

1. **'%m/%d/%Y'** - this is the format of date in my CSV file
2. **'%Y-%m-%d'** - this is the mysql format in which i want to convert my CSV field date while inserting data
3. **col1** - is the actual column of my table (having date data type)
4. **@d1** - is the dummy variable to use in set statement, you can take it any variable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (with `DATE`) and another solution, is to use the native mysql format `YYYYMMDD` ie `20120209`.
I haven't tried with `DATETIME` but I guess `YYYYMMDDhhmmss` will work.