# Importing a CSV to MySQL with different date format

Tags: mysql, csv, insert

I'm doing my first CSV import into MySQL and noticed that the date in the CSV has the format `31-Jan-2011`. How can I convert this to `2011-01-31` so I can place it in the DATE datatype? The first thing which came to mind is let PHP do the conversion then insert it into a 2nd table but I'm guessing that's...not right.

Comment: Looks like someone already answered this over at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616494/how-to-convert-csv-date-format-to-into-mysql-db. I'm posting it in case someone else has this question.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can replace format during importing data from the CSV file, for example -

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name.csv'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(id, column2, column3, @date_time_variable) -- read one of the field to variable
SET date_time_column = STR_TO_DATE(@date_time_variable, '%d-%b-%Y'); -- format this date-time variable
```

It will format the string like '31-Jan-2011' to a correct DATETIME data type.

More information here - [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%Y-%m-%d');
+------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%Y-%m-%d') |
+------------------------------------------------+
| 2009-10-04                                     | 
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

If the file isn't too big, load the CSV into Excel and use the formatting commands there to change the date representation.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really help with the SQL question. Furthermore, Excel isn't really a too that is easy to embed in a batch process.

Comment: This worked for me, simply changed the date format in excel for the column to "yyyy-mm-dd", saved as csv and imported.