# Format Date field in XAMPP SQL database to german layout (dd.mm.yyy)

Tags: mysql, date, phpmyadmin, xampp

i did a import of my excel list, which worked fine.
But then i saw that the date format was completely zeroed out.
Our format in the excel list was "dd.mm.yyyy"

I think the SQL server wants "yyyy.mm.dd"?

If so, how can i change the format of the DB field?

I think that these fields are the one i am looking for. But what do i enter here?

I tried to look it up in the help and google, but i found nothing special for the GUI

[Database date format fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCYgP.png)

Comment: Exacly. Thank you! 
So it is not possible to change HOW it is stored in the DB.
You have to format it at every query. Not very nice.

Comment: Pretty much. This might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8164237/2385479 , but generally MySQL expects incoming date information to correspond to a particular format so it knows how to parse it.