# Importing a txt to MySQL with different date format

Tags: python, mysql, stock-data

What I want to do is transfer the "12/26/17 14:30" in txt to "2017-12-26 14:30:00 " in MySQL

I've already tried this  [Importing a CSV to MySQL with different date format0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163079/importing-a-csv-to-mysql-with-different-date-format)

So my code looks like this

```
 create_tb_str = r'''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLENAME;
        CREATE TABLE TABLENAME (
        Datetime DATETIME,
        Open float(8,3),            
        High float(8,3),            
        Low float(8,3),             
        Close float(8,3), 
        Volume INT,                           
        PRIMARY KEY (Datetime)
        );'''
insert_tb_str = r''' LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'FILENAME'  
INTO TABLE  TABLENAME  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t\t'  
ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES
TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(@time, open, high, low, close, @dummy, volume);
SET Datetime = STR_TO_DATE(@time,'%y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S');   
'''
```

However, after I generate the .sql and try to import to my db, this is the result I get, the terminal can not recognize my table's column name.

```
$:~/Downloads/bartest$ mysql -u root -p bar -A < bartest.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR 1193 (HY000) at line 21: Unknown system variable 'Datetime'
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should connect to a specific database, not just smash around as root and create them in the `mysql` namespace.

Comment: You're using a reserved MySQL parameter as a `name` ---  `DATETIME` should **not** be used as a `name`.  I would rename your field to something less "parameter-ish"

Answer (score 0):

`STR_TO_DATE(@time,'%y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S');` is returning null as it's not matching the string input pattern.

Try something like this instead: `STR_TO_DATE('12/26/17 14:30','%m/%d/%y %k:%i');`

After extracting in DATE, convert it to your desired Date format.

To do in single step, you can also try: "SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '12/26/17 14:30');"

Hope that helps!